# Group by and count apperances in other column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My table look like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
|id    | action   |  building   | date       |
----------------------------------------------
|1     | IN       | 1000        | 01-01-2015 |
|2     | OUT      | 1000        | 01-01-2015 |
|3     | OUT      | 1000        | 05-01-2015 |
|4     | IN       | 2000        | 01-01-2015 |
----------------------------------------------
```

I would like to group the result by building and count the how many IN and OUT actions exists. Data and id doesn't matter in the result. The result should be like:

```
-------------------------
| Building   | IN | OUT |
-------------------------
| 1000       | 1  | 2   |
| 2000       | 1  | 0   |
-------------------------
```

The action column can only contain IN and OUT.

My best attempt is:

```
select distinct (action), building, count(*)
from table
group by action, building
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------
| action     | Building  | count(*) |
-------------------------------------
| IN         | 1000      | 1        |
| OUT        | 1000      | 2        |
| IN         | 2000      | 1        |
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select Building,
       sum(case when action = 'IN' then 1 else 0 end) as [IN],
       sum(case when action = 'OUT' then 1 else 0 end) as [OUT],
from TableName
group by Building
```

Comment: Outperformed me by 1 sec :=)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!!! How did you changed the layout of the table in the question, i wanted to do the same?

Comment: @Sebastian, you are just selecting text and press `{}`, to mark text as code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *conditional aggregation*:

```
select building, 
       count(CASE WHEN action = 'IN' THEN 1 END) AS 'IN',
       count(CASE WHEN action = 'OUT' THEN 1 END) AS 'OUT'
from table
group by building
```